# How to export a Numpy Array as a .tif so that it can be used as surface information in autoCAD

Tags: python-3.x, csv, tiff, shapefile, autocad

I imported a LiDAR surface file from a .tif and a Shapefile boundary into python.

```
Existing_Surface = 'FilePath/Existing_Surface.tif'
Fill_Boundary = 'FilePath/Fill_Boundary_polygon.shp'
```

I trimmed the .tif surface around the Shapefile and created a numpy array. Example array below.

```
existing_example_array = [[ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                          [ 4, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 5, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                          [ 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I then manipulated the values within the array. Example array below.

```
Proposed_example_array = [[  0,  1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [ 102, 1,  1, 2, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [  0, 103, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0], 
                          [ 104, 1,  1, 4, 0, 0, 0], 
                          [  0, 105, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0], 
                          [  0,  1,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Now with the proposed numpy array I am trying to export the data back into a readable file that could be used to build a surface in autoCAD.

I tried exporting the file with the following code using tifffle command:

```
data_folder = Path('FilePath/Proposed_example_array.tif')
tifffile.imsave( data_folder, Proposed_example_array)
```

This provides a format that autoCAD is not able to read as surface information, though I can put this in cad as am image. I believe that I am losing my projection and georeference when I am manipulating the values within a np.array. Its possible that exporting as a .tif isn't the best option and converting the numpy arrays to a .csv or a shapefile would provide better results.

Comment: I don't know or use AutoCAD, but I would imagine you can use `exiftool` to see the metadata in your `Existing_Surface.tif` and then compare it with the metadata of your home-grown TIFF and difference them. I assume you'll be able to determine what you need to add to make AutoCAD happy again. It is pretty simple to copy forward metadata from one file to another using `exiftool`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import tifffile as tiff
import numpy as np



Proposed_example_array = Proposed_example_array.astype(np.uint16)
tiff.imsave(data_folder, Proposed_example_array)
```

Comment: I am still receiving the error "Invalid DEM File" when attempting to use it to build a surface.